# err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF"

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terraform, virtualbox

I am trying to create ubuntu in an Oracle VM VirtualBox using terraform this is main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    virtualbox = {
      source = "shekeriev/virtualbox"
      version = "0.0.4"
    }
  }
}
resource "virtualbox_vm" "vm1" {
   count     = 2
  name      = format("node-%02d", count.index + 1)
  image     = "https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64/versions/20180903.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box"
  cpus      = 2
  memory    = "512 mib"
  
#   user_data = file("${path.module}/user_data")

  network_adapter {
    type           = "bridge"
    # device         = "IntelPro1000MTDesktop"
    # host_interface = "vboxnet1"
    # On Windows use this instead
    host_interface = "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
  }
  
output "IPAddress" {
  value = element(virtualbox_vm.vm1.*.network_adapter.0.ipv4_address, 1)
}
```

but it keep giving me the following error:

```
│ Error: can't set up VM properties: exit status 1
│
│   with virtualbox_vm.vm1[0],
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "virtualbox_vm" "vm1":
│   15: resource "virtualbox_vm" "vm1" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: can't set up VM properties: exit status 1
│
│   with virtualbox_vm.vm1[1],
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "virtualbox_vm" "vm1":
│   15: resource "virtualbox_vm" "vm1" {
│
╵
2023-02-07T17:06:10.579+0100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: removing lock metadata file .terraform.tfstate.lock.info
2023-02-07T17:06:10.580+0100 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: unlocked by closing terraform.tfstate     
2023-02-07T17:06:10.581+0100 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF"
2023-02-07T17:06:10.591+0100 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/shekeriev/virtualbox/0.0.4/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-virtualbox.exe pid=28956
2023-02-07T17:06:10.591+0100 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
```

the virtualboxes appears in the VirtualBox Manager with the operating system: Other/Unknown